# Ant: export jar with specific folder structure

Tags: plugins, ant, jar, export, bukkit

After searching around here for a while, I didn't find a solution for the following problem.

I have an eclipse project structure that looks like this:

```
├── bin
│   └── de
│       └── myname
│           └── myproject
│               └── MyClass.class
├── build.xml
├── plugin.yml
└── src
    └── de
        └── myname
            └── myproject
                └── MyClass.java
```

Now I want a jar to be exported with a folder structure similiar to this:

```
├── de
│   └── myname
│       └── myproject
│           └── MyClass.class
└── plugin.yml
```

How can I achieve this with an ant build file?

Bonus Question: can I export a jar without the `META-INF`-folder?

Comment: A jar without a `META-INF` folder is a zip. So you'd use the `<zip>` task the same way you use the `<jar>` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved it after reading about the [`Jar`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task again.

The following `build.xml` fits my needs perfectly, that's what i wanted.

```
<project name="MyPlugin.makejar" default="makejar">
    <target name="makejar" description="Create a jar for the MyPlugin project">
        <jar jarfile="the_path_we_export_to/MyPlugin.jar" basedir="." includes="plugin.yml">
            <fileset dir="bin/">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Feel free to use this in your own projects as I know how annoying it is to have to export the project every time even when you have made small changes in its code (the Eclipse exporting process is just a thing that is in my opinion a little bit too complicated and should be improved).